# How to differentiate betwen HTMLCollection and HTMLInputElement in IE?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of input elements (checkboxes) which is dynamic sometimes it contains one element sometimes more. How can I check in IE whether the object is an instance of HTMLInputElement or HTMLCollection?

Comment: Don't. Always work with a list of elements, even if it only contains one element.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not need any specific feature of HTMLCollection and your input name is **document.form.checkbox_name** then you can use below to access it as an array:

```
var chkarr = document.form.checkbox_name ;

if( chkarr.length == undefined )
{
    chkarr = [ chkarr ] ;
}

chkarr[ 0 ].checked = true ;
// .. etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going with the following solution now

```
buttons = myForm.elements['buttons'];
var objType = {}.toString.call(buttons);
if(objType != '[object HTMLInputElement]')
{
    alert('Collection');
}
else
{
    alert('Single');
}
```

Comment: If you use `var buttons = myForm.getElementsByName('buttons');`, then you will always have a list of elements.